# Where to specifying table relation for vb.net application?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

There is an MS Access database which i'm planning to use to store my inventory data. I am trying to built an vb.net App and I'm confused about where to specify table relation as there are some relation between Product-Category-SubCategory so and so..

As I can see there are two ways to do it, First one is to do it in MS Access itself and the other is within the Dataset in Visual studio. Problem is that i don't know which would be a sensible choice as I am new to vb.net.

Can somebody give me an advice on this matter.?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by specifying the relation? Do you want to enforce referential integrity?

Comment: Yes.I want to make sure the user can not enter invalid data. I don't want the user to add invalid 'category' or to create multiple look alike 'Category' due to an typing error.

Comment: If there are not too many choices you can bind combo boxes with the available choices from the database. Then when category is selected fill the sub category combo box based on the selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referential integrity is handled at the database level, not at the application level.

Thus, you need to specify your relations in Access, not in the VB.Net application. You can do this under *Database Tools* -> *Relationships*

However, you might also want to do some sort of checking at the application level to avoid a run-time error when invalid data is inserted into the database.